# "Долго ли, коротко ли, перевалы сменялись долинами, на равнинах лежали поля"?

Tags: точное-словоупотребление

> Долго ли, коротко ли, перевалы сменялись долинами, горы сурово
>   поглядывали на равнины, на равнинах лежали поля.

Очень сильно интересуюсь лежащими на равнинах полями и идиомой, открывающей пленэр... То ли она "через некоторое время", то ли "в продолжение какого-то времени", что для меня вещи разные.

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Долго ли, коротко ли, **но** перевалы сменялись долинами, горы сурово поглядывали на равнины, **на равнинах зеленели возделанные  поля.***

1) **Долго ли, коротко ли.** Я это выражение понимаю как рано или поздно, но что-то происходит, что-то меняется. В данном случае меняется картина местности.

2) **Поля не могут лежать на долинах**, так как в одном из значений поле — это безлесная равнина. Но поле может быть частью равнины, если это возделанный участок земли.

ПОЛЕ,  1. Безлесная равнина. 2. Обрабатываемая под посев земля, возделанный участок.